# PHP for loop with Database and API Data only calculates 1 result

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I try to loop trough a php script to calculate a Total Holding of a Persons Portfolio. But my code only puts out one calculated field instead of all from the Database.

My DB looks like this:

```
id          email          amount     currency     date_when_bought      price_when_bought
33          test@test.com  100        BTC          2019-04-17            4000
34          test@test.com  50         ETH          2019-04-17            150
```

My Code (pretty messy)

```
<?php
include('databasecon.php');



    //// GET API JSON DATA
    $coinData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRB,IOTA,XRP,XLM,TRX,LINK,USDT&tsyms=USD'), true);

    //SELECT ALL MAIL
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM user_data");
    $email_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $email_array[] = $row['email'];
    };


    // PORTFOLIO ARRAYS
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($email_array); $i++) {

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM crypto_data WHERE email = '$email_array[$i]'");


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
     $myCoins[$row['currency']] = array('balance' => $row['amount'],
                                    'boughtprice' => $row['price_when_bought']);
     };



 // 0 VALUES FOR CALCULATION
 $portfolioValue = 0;
 $totalNET = 0;
 $Value24H = 0;

 // information in json path ['RAW'] so safeguard here to be sure it exists
 if (isset($coinData['RAW'])) {
   // then loop on all entries $cryptoSymbol will contain for example BTC and cryptoInfo the array USD => [...]
   foreach($coinData['RAW'] as $cryptoSymbol => $cryptoInfo) {
      // safeguard, check path [USD][FROMSYMBOL] exists
      if (!isset($cryptoInfo['USD']) || !isset($cryptoInfo['USD']['FROMSYMBOL'])) {
         // log or do whatever to handle error here
         echo "no path [USD][FROMSYMBOL] found for crypto: " . $cryptoSymbol . PHP_EOL;
         continue;
  }

      // Symbol in on your json path/array [USD][FROMSYMBOL]
      $thisCoinSymbol = $cryptoInfo['USD']['FROMSYMBOL'];
      $coinHeld = array_key_exists($thisCoinSymbol, $myCoins);
      // Only retour held
      if ( !$coinHeld ) { continue; }


       // get price:
             $thisCoinPrice = $cryptoInfo['USD']['PRICE'];

       // get symbol holding:
          if ($coinHeld) {
             $myBalance_units = $myCoins[$thisCoinSymbol]['balance'];
             };

       // calculate total holdings:
           if ($coinHeld) {
              $myBalance_USD = $myBalance_units * $thisCoinPrice;
              $portfolioValue += $myBalance_USD;
              };

                echo '<br>';
                echo $email_array[$i];
                echo $portfolioValue . PHP_EOL;
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';

                $myCoins = null;

   }}};
?>
```

The Steps are:

```
1 API connection
2 Select Mail adresses from user_data and put them into an Array
3 start for-loop with size of the email_array
4 Query the crypto_data DB to get all results from that mail
5 Put all Data from crypto_data into Array
6 foreach loop the API
7 Calculations
8 Echo the results
9 null $myCoins
```

As a result, I get the right Mail Adress + the second row (id 33) calculated with the actual price. But my Result should also plus count id 33 and 34 to get the total result.

To clearify, I get "100 * Price of BTC" , but I need "100 * Price of BTC + 50 * Price of ETH"

Somehow my code only puts out 1 row, but does not calculate them like I want to do so here:

```
// calculate total holdings:
           if ($coinHeld) {
              $myBalance_USD = $myBalance_units * $thisCoinPrice;
              $portfolioValue += $myBalance_USD;
              };
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I think your issue is with using select distinct, because then you only get one row per email so you won't have the extra rows, Ithink you would be better using a group by and using mysql sum functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few bugs in your code, such as:

- You are setting `$myCoins` to `null` immediately after the first iteration of `foreach` loop, so `array_key_exists()` function will fail in the next iteration. Remove it entirely, there's no need of setting `$myCoins` to `null`.
- Keep the below just inside the outer `for` loop. You should not print the portfolio value for each iteration of `foreach` loop, rather print the *aggregated* portfolio value for each email address.

  ```
  echo '<br>';
  echo $email_array[$i];
  echo $portfolioValue . PHP_EOL;
  echo '<br>';
  echo '<br>';
  ```
- Reset `$portfolioValue` value to `0` at the end of the `for` loop.

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    include('databasecon.php');

    // GET API JSON DATA
    $coinData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRB,IOTA,XRP,XLM,TRX,LINK,USDT&tsyms=USD'), true);

    //SELECT ALL MAIL
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM user_data");
    $email_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $email_array[] = $row['email'];
    }

    // PORTFOLIO ARRAYS
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($email_array); $i++) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM crypto_data WHERE email = '$email_array[$i]'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $myCoins[$row['currency']] = array('balance' => $row['amount'], 'boughtprice' => $row['price_when_bought']);
        }

        // 0 VALUES FOR CALCULATION
        $portfolioValue = 0;
        $totalNET = 0;
        $Value24H = 0;

        // information in json path ['RAW'] so safeguard here to be sure it exists
        if (isset($coinData['RAW'])) {
            // then loop on all entries $cryptoSymbol will contain for example BTC and cryptoInfo the array USD => [...]
            foreach($coinData['RAW'] as $cryptoSymbol => $cryptoInfo) {
                // safeguard, check path [USD][FROMSYMBOL] exists
                if (!isset($cryptoInfo['USD']) || !isset($cryptoInfo['USD']['FROMSYMBOL'])) {
                    // log or do whatever to handle error here
                    echo "no path [USD][FROMSYMBOL] found for crypto: " . $cryptoSymbol . PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }

                // Symbol in on your json path/array [USD][FROMSYMBOL]
                $thisCoinSymbol = $cryptoInfo['USD']['FROMSYMBOL'];
                $coinHeld = array_key_exists($thisCoinSymbol, $myCoins);
                // Only retour held
                if ( !$coinHeld ) { continue; }

                // get price:
                $thisCoinPrice = $cryptoInfo['USD']['PRICE'];

                // get symbol holding:
                if ($coinHeld) {
                    $myBalance_units = $myCoins[$thisCoinSymbol]['balance'];
                }

                // calculate total holdings:
                if ($coinHeld) {
                    $myBalance_USD = $myBalance_units * $thisCoinPrice;
                    $portfolioValue += $myBalance_USD;
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<br>';
        echo $email_array[$i];
        echo $portfolioValue . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        $portfolioValue = 0;
    }
?>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the Error was the "};" that was not set after the last calculation I made before the echoes, to close the" foreach($coinData['RAW']" loop. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Dharman I agree, I was more focused on fixing the logical part, and I somehow missed to add an additional sidenote(which I always do wherever necessary). Added now.